How to find a demographic data from the internet?
I am looking for a demographic data related to US that has a state, county, metropolitan, population, income, and so on. I tried to obtained from data.census.gov but it returns the data for 5 years estimated subjected tables. As a result, I find the data is cluttered and hard to understand. Is there a easy way to find the data?
